# Modify argument value with the Spring Data JPA Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data

I do have a Spring Data JPA repository with a custom method:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long> {
    List<Entity> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

And I would like to somehow modify the `name` (e.g. escape the `%` and `_`, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-216) value before calling the method.

My proposed solution was to create a `CustomString` and a  `Converter<CustomString, String>` with required business logic in it. But even if I change the signature to `findByNameIgnoreCase(CustomString name)`, the `converter` is not used and the original `CustomString` is passed to the `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Is there any other way how to do that without creating any extra `Services` and wrapping the `repository` call?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just convert the string before invoking the repository method?

Smth like this:

```
entityRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(transformNameIntoSomethingElse(name));
```

Comment: Yes, that is definitively possible :). I was just curious if there is some more transparent way to do that and I was surprised that the Converter did not worked :).